# Retrieve data from Realtime database Firebase in node.js Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

Hey y'all I've been pretty stumped here. I have been creating a cloud function for payment
intents for my app in Stripe, and called back the value for price in my cloud function, but it just can't seem to retrieve it. I tested the function without the callback and it seemed to work fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Database
[image: Database]

Stripe error
[image: Stripe error]

'''
My function code

```
exports.paymentStripe = functions.firestore.document('Payment/{docId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  console.log(snap.path);
  console.log(snap.data);

  const value = snap.data();
  var price = value.amount;
  var idStripeAccountDriver = value.idStripeAccountDriver;

  async function run() {

    console.log(snap.path);
    console.log(snap.data());
    console.log(price);

    const paymentDriver = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: price / 100 * 5,
      currency: 'usd',
    }, {
      stripeAccount:idStripeAccountDriver,
    });
  };
  return run();
});

'''
```

Comment: `value.price` should be `value.amount`. Also, don't forget your `return` statement in `return run()`.

Comment: @samthecodingman I am still getting the same stripe error. Could the pathway to my payment collection be wrong?

Comment: After making the change, have you redeployed/restarted the emulator? If so and it's still not working, you should log the value of `snap.path` and `snap.data()` to see what the function is being fed.

Comment: @samthecodingman I added console logs but don't see anything. Could it be an error in my snap code?

Answer (score 0):

The below block of code is similar to how I would implement the function of the code you posted. It also will log any problems with the values provided and the problems of the Stripe API call.

```
exports.paymentStripe = functions.firestore.document('Payment/{docId}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => { // <-- note addition of async here
    // == extract relevant data ==
    const { amount, idStripeAccountDriver } = snap.data();

    // == validate data ==
    if (amount === undefined || amount === null) { // may be zero?
      console.error(`Firestore document at "${snap.path}" was missing the required field: amount`);
      return;
    } else if (typeof amount !== "number") {
      console.error(`Firestore document at "${snap.path}" contained a non-numeric value for the required field: amount`);
      return;
    }

    if (!idStripeAccountDriver) { // can't be falsy (undefined, null, 0, <empty>, etc.)
      console.error(`Firestore document at "${snap.path}" was missing the required field: idStripeAccountDriver`);
      return;
    }

    try {
      // == use extracted data ==
      const paymentDriver = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
        {
          amount: (amount * 5) / 100, // <-- avoids floating point math issues
          currency: 'usd'
        },
        {
          stripeAccount: idStripeAccountDriver
        }
      );

      // == handle successful result ==
      console.log(`Payment for "${snap.path}" created successfully`);

      // TODO: Do something with paymentDriver
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`Stripe rejected create payment request for "${snap.path}"`, err);
    }
  });
```